# APIs, Scripts, Browser Add-Ons, and PhilSE Backend

Tags: feature-request, chat, stackexchange

**2020-11-07:** Since asking, I've found a link to https://stackapps.com/ in another post.

Arrrrgh,

**Unfurling of Flag**

In the spirit of shared ownership, I'm seizing this ghost ship (read inactive post) to express my interest in finding collaborators (of the non-Vichy sort) to build tools for two utilities I use daily: [BeefText](https://beeftext.org/) and [Roam](http://roamresearch.com/). (I also use Grammarly when editing text.)

**BeefText**

BeefText is just a shim in the keyboard input to translate a short string to a longer one, old-school macro style. For instance, when I spot a user with a low rating posting for the first time, I simply type:

> 'phwelnew'

and the app substitutes:

> Welcome to SE Philosophy! Thanks for your contribution. Please take a quick moment to take the [tour](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/tour) or find [help](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/help). You can perform [searches here](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/search) or seek additional clarification at the [meta site](https://philosophy.meta.stackexchange.com/). Don't forget, when someone has answered your question, you can click on the checkmark to reward the contributor.

Another example is 'phrwpuod' which produces:

> [universe of discourse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_of_discourse#Universe_of_discourse)

Ultimately translating into:

> [universe of discourse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_of_discourse#Universe_of_discourse)

For those of you who are digitally inclined, the application has a simple UI for data entry, but also an import function. I've been messing around with various policies for the target strings, and have something functional.

**Roam**

The other utility Roam is a web-based, lightweight content utility which uses a shallow markup syntax for formatting, small widgets, and linking. I happen to use it in tandem with [DropBox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dropbox_(service)), a distributed file system in lieu of a website. It uses a simple flat-file or JSON export option and has an API.

Over the last few months, I've really have tried to psychologically transition from an old-school client-server mentality to a distributed services way of thinking. I've been kicking around ideas like building a text parser to auto-insert links, import and export content for building lists, scraping text to look at technical aspects of language (Anyone wonder who is the most referenced user on the site?)

**PhilSE Backend**

As I'm at the cusp of 5,000, I know I'll have access to the backend for writing SQL queries. (I took a peek before I dipped under the threshold). I have a strange infatuation with data, and I'm more than willing to start building/cataloging reporting to supplement whatever the 5000+ club has. Also, I'm genuinely curious about the technology practice more widely used across the various communitites.

Anyway, we're all busy, doubly so in a global pandemic, but if anyone has time, energy, curiosity, or skills and wants to collaborate on technology or any aspect of crowd-sourcing philosophical pedagogy on or off this platform, X marks the spot.

Thanks!
jd
2020-10-30

**Original Crew of Comandeered Ship**

SEP doesn't seem to have an API, so presumably, the integration would be somewhat 'messy' (involve scraping the page) -- but this would be a *really* nice-to-have feature in our stack's chat space. A few notes on the site structure:

- A table of contents for the SEP is available here: http://plato.stanford.edu/contents.html. (If a page isn't listed here, it doesn't have an entry. The direct link to each entry is also here.)
- The search action uses URLs of the form: http://plato.stanford.edu/search/searcher.py?query=something
- The markup is relatively 'plain' and there's not a lot of embedded metadata, so the integration may be somewhat brittle/complex. (It does seem to be that article content is always under the first 'p'-tag on the page if the entry exists.)

SEP doesn't seem to have an API, so presumably, the integration would be somewhat 'messy' (involve scraping the page) -- but this would be a *really* nice-to-have feature in our stack's chat space. A few notes on the site structure:

- A table of contents for the SEP is available here: http://plato.stanford.edu/contents.html. (If a page isn't listed here, it doesn't have an entry. The direct link to each entry is also here.)
- The search action uses URLs of the form: http://plato.stanford.edu/search/searcher.py?query=something
- The markup is relatively 'plain' and there's not a lot of embedded metadata, so the integration may be somewhat brittle/complex. (It does seem to be that article content is always under the first 'p'-tag on the page if the entry exists.)

Comment: Outstanding question that looks to have been neglected. Has your information about this matter evolved? After a year of monkeying around, I was thinking about using the Firefox API and BeefText to build something similar.

Comment: I am not deep enough into the backend and coding part to be of any help, but BeefText really sound like an interesting piece of software ;) Maybe I could have a look into some contacts since there are quite some people out there coding and actively using SE queries  for moderation purposes (charcoal/metasmoke comes to mind).